# Error : dlopen failed: library "libopencv_java490.so" not found

Tags: java, android, kotlin, opencv

I added OpenCV 4.9.0 in my kotlin-android project from [here](https://opencv.org/releases/). After connection and build my app, i didn't see any issue. I wanted to cut video and get a frame, using VideoCapture and after running the application i got this error:

> UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libopencv_java490.so" not found

The project has only these files "libopencv_java4.so"

```
object VideoUtils {
    fun getFirsFrameFromVideo(videoPath: String): Mat? {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)
        val videoCapture = VideoCapture()
        if (!videoCapture.isOpened){
            println("DON'T OPENED VIDEO")
            return null
        }
        val frame = Mat()
        videoCapture.read(frame)
        if (frame.empty()){
            println("EMPTY FRAME")
            return null
        }
        return frame
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to me like a bug in the OpenCV build environment for the Android package.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the official 4.9.0 release. Same issue occurs whether you reference the pre-built libraries or build from source. If you are building from source, you can fix it temporarily (until an official fix is available) by updating Core.java to return the correct native library name. Changing it
from:

```
private static String getNativeLibraryName() { return "opencv_java490"; }
```

to:

```
private static String getNativeLibraryName() { return "opencv_java4"; }
```

should do the trick for the time being.